# Remove before echoing

Tags: php

Say I have a list like this

```
hello1
hello2
hello3
hello4
goodbye
hello6
hello7
hello8
```

How can I remove just the `goodbye` and print `everything else` besides goodbye?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`unset`](http://php.net/unset) and [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) like this:

```
$array = array('hello1','hello2','hello3','hello4','goodbye','hello6','hello7','hello8');
if(($key = array_search('goodbye', $array)) !== FALSE) 
   unset($array[$key]);
```

This does two things in one `if` statement:

If the assigned value of `$key` (the return value of `array_search`) is truthy, then proceed and use it as an index, otherwise, don't do anything.
This is necessary because if the return value of `array_search` is `FALSE`, then the resulting would be `$array[FALSE]` which would not be the intended behavior at all.

Comment: Just a detail: Instead of the "do nothing, when 'true'" `if($array[$k] == $el) continue; $ar[$k] = $v` you should specify, when to do something. `if ($v != $el) $ar[] = $v;`

Comment: @KingCrunch, I'm not sure I understand - could you please rephrase?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not sure I'll be able to use this. I don't know what the results are going to be, that was just a example. I'm scraping images from a page and this one static.gif image pops up and I just want to remove it.

Comment: @mike More detail would be very much appreciated

Comment: @Jacob In short: Avoid `break` and `continue` (and `goto` since 5.3) where avoidable. I know, its useful some times, but here its unnecessary. Instead of saying "Restart loop, if this is the item, that should not be added", the 'if'-statement is clearer when it says "Add all items, that are not the item you are looking for". OK, I see you rewrite your whole answer ... This does not match anymore ;)

Comment: I setup a cron job to call this my function daily to scrap all images on a page from one site, but it scrapes images I don't want such as movie.gif. It will scrape 10 files(0-10).jpg and inbetween each it includes the movie.gif so 10 of them. I don't want movie.gif, so how can I remove it from the for each?

Comment: @mike instead of waiting until the value ends up in your resulting array, why don't you set up and `$exclude` array and just stick a `continue` in your directory loop `if` the current filename is in the `$exclude` array?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know where the goodbye is in the list? is the goodbye the only situation you want to filter it?

set an `if(currentStr != "goodbye"){ do action}` in your loop

Answer (score 1):

Expecting, that you really have a list

```
$x = array('hello1','hello2','hello3','hello4','goodbye','hello6','hello7','hello8');
```

you just iterate over this list and dont output the unwanted entry

```
foreach ($x as $entry) {
    if ($entry != 'goodbye') echo $entry;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to find the key of entry use [array_search](http://php.net/array_search) , after you can unset this 
entry

```
$key = array_search('goodbye', $array);     
unset($array[$key]);
```

Comment: See my answer for the way this should really be done. The return value of `array_search` should be checked for `FALSE`.